# For-loops From Lists

Tags: shell, for-loop, curl

Is there a way to make the "write" a nested for-loop that would only call the elements in the lists based on their position.

e.g.

```
List 1 = {A,B,C}
List 2 = {1, 2,3}
```

The call would only be

```
A1 
B2
C3
```

i.e. 1st element in List_1 would only be called together with the 1st element in List_2, etc.

I have this code

```
for i in {A,B,C,D}; do for j in {0,1,2,3}; do echo curl -b cookies.txt "https://mydomain(dot)com/${i} -d 'status=0&version=${j}'";done done;
```

However, this calls all the possible combinations

```
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/A -d 'status=0&version=0'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/A -d 'status=0&version=1'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/A -d 'status=0&version=2'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/A -d 'status=0&version=3'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/B -d 'status=0&version=0'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/B -d 'status=0&version=1'
etc
```

Where as I would only like the code to call only

```
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/A -d 'status=0&version=0'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/B -d 'status=0&version=1'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/C -d 'status=0&version=2'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/D -d 'status=0&version=3'
```

Is this possible with a structure similar to what I shared?
Thank you

Comment: Appreciate it Benjamin - the "Question" you pointed me towards resolved my issue.